# Java - Array outputing null

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, debugging

My program is supposed to output labels. All of the input works when I run it but the output is wrong and all that it outputs is `null`, for every part of the label except for the box number.

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MailOrderpractice {

    static String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare variables
        String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
        String numBoxesInput;
        int numBoxes;
        String enterAnother = "Y";
        int counter;

        getLabelData();

        numBoxesInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of boxes in the order:");
        numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesInput);

        // begin outer loop logic that determines when user is finished entering mail orders
        while (enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            counter = 1;
            // begin the inner loop to display a label and increment the counter
            while (counter <= numBoxes) {
                System.out.println(nameAddressArray[0] + " " + nameAddressArray[1] + " " + nameAddressArray[2]);
                System.out.println(nameAddressArray[3]);
                System.out.println(nameAddressArray[4] + ", " + nameAddressArray[5] + " " + nameAddressArray[6]);
                System.out.println("Box " + counter + " of " + numBoxes);
                System.out.println();
                counter = counter + 1;
            }

            enterAnother = " "; // initialize the variable to something other than "Y" before sending the prompt
            enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to produce more labels? Y or N");

            while (!enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                enterAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Invalid Response. Please enter Y or N.",
                    "DATA ENTRY ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } // end while

            if (enterAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                getLabelData();
                numBoxesInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of boxes in the order:");
                numBoxes = Integer.parseInt(numBoxesInput);
            } // end if
        } // end while

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void getLabelData() {
        nameAddressArray[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter title (Mr., Ms., Dr., etc.): ");
        nameAddressArray[1] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name: ");
        nameAddressArray[2] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter lastname: ");
        nameAddressArray[3] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter street address: ");
        nameAddressArray[4] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter city: ");
        nameAddressArray[5] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter state (IL, MO, etc.): ");
        nameAddressArray[6] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter zip (e.g., 62025): ");
    }
```

Comment: try to debug your code

Comment: The fact that it compiles does not mean it is error free. If it was error free you wouldn't be posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `nameAddressArray` is declared twice. You have a `static` field

```
static String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
```

You also have a local variable with the same name in the `main` method.

```
String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
```

Your `main` method is putting values into the second array, whereas your `getLabelData` method is using the values from the `static` field, and these are all the initial value (`null`).

One way to solve this problem is to just get rid of the local variable. Then both parts of the code will use the same array.

Alternatively, you could get rid of the static field, and pass the array as a parameter to the `getLabelData` method. This is probably a better solution, as mutable static fields are generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to comment this line into Main method(),

```
 //  String nameAddressArray[] = new String[7];
```

Comment: I have that right after my public class, is that not right and it wont let me state it twice.  And i have it after my public static void main.

Comment: now it's works perfectly as per you want or not ? If yes then kindly accept my answer and upvote.

Comment: no it dosnt work. im not sure where you mean i should add it, since it is already there

Comment: @Grace Exactly. It's declared twice. Either delete the one in main or comment it out by putting `//` at the beginning as suggested in this (correct) answer.

Comment: @Grace Hey what the hell ? all i know my answer is correct. why go for distance as well as down vote.

Comment: I just recommend you short and sweet trick and you put me down voted.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Im just a little confused as to what it means to comment this line into Main method(). sorry

Comment: @Grace if you commenting it then also your problem solved. have you ever tried ?

Comment: @vishalgajera It wasn't Grace. OP does not have enough rep to downvote.

Comment: @Grace Commenting out means that the line is not executed when the program is run.

Comment: @PaulBoddington  thanks you guys. it still dosen't quite fix it however. if i take out the first one i just get errors and if i take out the second one it works but gives me a weird line at the end when its done running. sorry im kinda dumb and confused.  i really do appreciate your help.

Comment: @Grace You're not dumb at all. Most questions from new users on this site are incomprehensible or don't compile, so yours is MUCH better than the average. However, this site is about specific programming problems, and it's not a good idea to keep changing the question until your entire program works. You have 2 correct answers to your original question. You should accept one of them (check the tick next to the answer) and ask another question if you are still having issues.